# Cloning a form with jQuery and file inputs

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, concept

I'm trying to figure out the most effective way to allow a user to clone a form with file inputs and retain their values. I'm aware this isn't actually possible for security reasons, JS returns a fakepath in the cloned value. Also just cloning the values would result in the same files getting uploaded in the cloned form group which is inefficient anyway.

It gets tricker as the user should be able to add or delete files to the to the second form group so some files may be removed and some may be added.

The only way I can think of getting this to work is to generate a hidden field for each file input that would serve as an index and check to see if any files were removed and process the new files separately.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. The app is built in Laravel but to be honest concepts would be just as useful.

Cheers!

Comment: `$("form").clone()` before submit does not work?

Comment: How about just cloning the inputs you're interested in? instead of the full form...

Comment: @JLF Nope the value is altered so that a fakepath is returned instead for security reasons. I see why that happens but I kind of wish it was allowed if you're not actually altering the value and just cloning it but then again you would have access to the path which is dangerous. E.g if you return the cloned object you would be able to see the path.

Comment: @monxas ... because it doesn't work for security reasons?

Comment: I meant other input (texts, etc). If you only have file inputs I can't understand why would you want to clone them, since 1 you can't. 2 it would upload the same file twice, witch you already said doesn't make sense.

Comment: @monxas Each form field group is a job request. Each bit of data needs to be referenced in each job so that the person fulfilling the request knows what's required. As I said my question users need to be able to delete files that mightn't be required for the second job while other files may be relevant and need to be referenced somehow.

Comment: It's hard for me to fully understand the process without seeing the form. In my head that looks like a multistep form. if the first job requires the files, you need to upload them no matter what. then submit that form. then, present the user with a new form and showing the uploaded files in the first form. You're talking about different jobs, I don't get why they should be created in just one step, when such changes need to be done.

Comment: @monxas I'll try to explain it a bit better. Say you were ordering custom made t-shirts and there was an option to add another t-shirt to your order in one form on one page. When you click to add a second t-shirt it copies over the data from the first shirt as you might want to keep some of the info including the images you uploaded. That's basically it.

Comment: I would add a check in the second form- [  ] use images already uploaded in previous t-shirt? or some text like that.  the check could show/hide a new file input for the new upload. I think it's the cleanest/easiest way to do it.

Comment: @monxas Yeah that's what I'm thinking and started to develop now. I was hoping there might be a slightly easier workaround but it looks like there isn't. Thanks for your help!